# Making tab completion look anywhere in the word

Tags: bash, input, auto-completion

This completion mode probably has a name, I just don't know what it is.

In Sublime Text the auto complete works in a way that the typed letters are searched for in the same order but they are not required to exactly follow each other.

For example, typing "rf" will match "runfile"

I am pasting a screencast of how Sublime completion works, and I am wondering if there is any way to make such a completion work in the linux command line.

[image]

Comment: From what do you want to complete? From filenames in your current directory or from an array with names or from a whitespace separated  string of names?

Comment: I wish it will complete from the same source it normally does if possible. So filenames in the current directory, executables in the path, and even files in other directories, if I start the completion with `/path/to/file`. If this complicates things, then perhaps just filenames in the current directory (without damaging the ability to find executables and other paths, at least in the 'normal' way).